# Minimum spanning tree with two minimum edge weights

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees

Given an undirected weighted graph $G$ with two edges of minimum weight and all other edges are distinct. Does G have a unique minimum spanning tree?

I know the proof for if all edge weights are distinct (it does give a unique MST) and I am thinking that if two edges of minimum weight are in $G$ then I should be able to show a counter example. But so far I have not been able to produce one.

So my question is does it give a unique MST if the graph $G$ contains two minimum weight edges?

Answer (score 5):

Yes $G$ has a unique MST (assuming it is not a multigraph). Take a look at Kruskal's algorithm: the edges are ordered ascending by weight and then added to the MST unless there is a cycle. After adding the two minimum edges, you can't have a cycle, therefore both are in the MST.

Edit: As Paresh pointed out, this is not a complete proof, since there may be MSTs which cannot be produced by Kruskal's after permutating equally weighted edges in the sorted list. But Kruskal's is in fact able to produce any MST. [Proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779113/1122095).

Comment: This is exactly the answer I had written, before I realized that the proof is not rigorous, and probably incorrect, and so deleted my answer. Kruskal's algo gives optimal weight of MST, but says nothing about whether such an MST is the only possible one. You can't say the MST will be unique from Kruskal's. Have a look [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~leon/cs-mcs401-s08/handouts/mst.pdf) for how the case for all distinct weights is proven.

Comment: Nice! Good to know that :)

Comment: Your observation is not an answer, and if you think your linked answer is correct, IMO is better to include it as quoted in your answer.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri please clarify "Your observation is not an answer"

Comment: "Yes G has a unique MST (assuming it is not a multigraph). Take a look at Kruskal's algorithm: the edges are ordered ascending by weight and then added to the MST unless there is a cycle. After adding the two minimum edges, you can't have a cycle, therefore both are in the MST."

Comment: I know you understand it's not true answer:"As Paresh pointed out, this is not a complete proof", but still, what you wrote in first paragraph is intuition, not mathematical proof.

Comment: You are correct, the first paragraph wasn't enough. This is why I edited it. Please point out why it isn't a answer in its current form (aside from citation), so I can improve it.

Comment: Nice to see my proof that Kruskal's algorithm can produce every MST is helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

To build a minimum spanning tree you will order edges by weights from smallest to largest. An edge is included as long as it does not make a cycle. If there are two minimum weight edges, then these edges are first and second. The first two edges do not make a cycle. Therefore, since all other edges are distinct, then you will end up with one minimum spanning tree. That is, whatever order of selecing the two minimum edges, the tree would be the same. QED.

A bit of clarification: 
Whether you are using Prim or Kruskal, the same result applies. Here is why. Kruskal order ALL edges ascendingly. In Prim, at each node $v$, the edges are ordered ascendingly in this manner $(v,u)$ where $u$ is a neighbor of $v$. Whenever an edge $(u,v)$ is selected, the edge $(v,u)$ is deleted [note they are the same since it is an undirected edge]. The edge with smallest minimum weight $e _{min(1)} =(x,y)$ is the first in the global ordering. It also should be the first at node x and y otherwise it is not the smallest. The argument applies to the second minimum edge $e _{min(2)}$.

In general, Kruskal follows a total order of edges, while Prim uses a partial order of edges.

Comment: This is the third answer of the same type, the first being mine. Unfortunately, the proof I believe is not rigorous, and probably wrong, although the result might be correct, hence I deleted it. What you are referring to is the Kruskal's algorithm. It only gives the optimal weight MST, not the only MST. In other words, how do you show that there is no other MST which has the same total weight as this, but is different. For example, how do you know that Prim's algo will also generate the same MST?

Comment: See [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~leon/cs-mcs401-s08/handouts/mst.pdf) for a proof of the case of all distinct weights.

Comment: @Paresh. I would really be interested in knowing how come it is a wrong proof. I dont mind if I am wrong. But I just want to point out that there is only "two" minimum weighted edges, and both will have to be included.

Comment: @Paresh: Also, i dont think this is the third answer of the same type of question. When I wrote it, there were no answers.

Comment: Probably I did not phrase it very well. I meant that the proof is incomplete. And by *probably wrong*, I meant the approach. I was not sure if the correct proof takes this approach or some other approach. For the reason why this proof is incomplete, take for example, the Prim's algorithm (instead of the Kruskal's). We start from a random vertex, and grow the MST from there. Then, the minimum weight edges might be encountered later, and one of them might form a cycle. In other words, what prevents one of the min weight edges being left out for a different MST with the same total weight?

Comment: As Simon points out in his answer, there is a way to show that the Kruskal's algo will generate all possible MST's for every ordering of equal weight edges. For this case, the only two possible orderings are for which of the min-weight edges is picked first. And as you show, it does not matter and the same MST results.

Comment: So basically, the missing component is only the fact that no MST can be formed which leaves out one or both of the two minimum weight edges, and still has the optimal total weight. Or maybe I am totally missing something obvious :(

Comment: And both the previous answers were deleted. I deleted mine, and Simon deleted his before he restored his answer after adding the proof for how those are the only possible MST's. I got nowhere with trying to prove this, or that any MST produced by Prim's can also be produced by Kruskal's. I really hope I am not ignoring something obvious in your proof, but I have to admit, given the added fact about Kruskal's that Simon added, this becomes much more convincing.

Comment: whether you are using Prim or Kruskal, the same result applies. Here is why. Kruskal order ALL edges ascendingly. In Prim, at each node $v$, the edges are ordered ascendingly in this manner $(v,u)$ where $u$ is a neighbor of $v$. Whenever an edge $(u,v)$ is selected, the edge $(v,u)$ is deleted [note they are the same since it is an undirected edge]. The edge with smallest minimum weight $e _{min(1)} = (x,y)$ is the first in the global ordering. It also should be the first at node $x$ and $y$ otherwise it is not the smallest. The argument applies to the second minimum edge $e _{min(2)}$.

Comment: I wish this clarifies the point. In general, Kruskal follows a total order of edges, while Prim's follows a partial order. --- Anyway, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Aah! Your nice explanation clears it up. Somehow, just the Kruskal ordering did not seem very convincing to me. You give a nice explanation. Thanks! Perhaps you could also add this to your answer for people like me who have doubts :)

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here is a proof that does not rely on any algorithm such as Kruskal's algorithm or Prim's algorithm.

For any cycle $C$ in $G$, $C$ has 3 or more than edges, one of which must weigh differently from the (global) minimum weight. So the maximum edge-weight of $C$ is not the global minimum weight. Since except two edges of the global minimum weight, all other edges in $G$ weigh distinctly, $C$ must have a unique heaviest edge. Let $e$ be an arbitrary edge in $G$. If $e$ is not the unique heaviest edge in any cycle, then it is not a heaviest edge in any cycle. According to [the characterization by "extreme cycle edge" of uniqueness of MST](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95739/91753), $G$ has a unique MST.