# question about algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, weighted-graphs

as you know we have equivalent condition for graphs so I want to ask a very basic question and please help me what is exactly w1(e1) and w1(e2) and w2(e1) and w2(e1) ?
If e1 means path from A to B so w1 means the weight of the path e1 and so what about w2 and what does it mean means ?
is there any link for this kind of topic to understand better ?

thank you so much

this is main question

[image]

Comment: Where are you reading this from? Upload a photo of it or provide a link.

Comment: Please merge your comment into seamless question post via edit, there should be a standalone question that doesn't require reading comments. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question provide a [full reference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for the source where you encountered the quoted material.  Please transcribe the mathematics into text or MathJax, rather than including a picture.  Thank you.

Comment: frankly speaking it doesn't have any reference and this question is on paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution provided here is highly inelegant as it uses a lemma which is a more general result. This 'solution' should instead be considered as more of a hint: a minimal solution can instead be found by extracting the most relevant parts of the proof of the lemma.**

Note that $w_1(e_1)<w_1(e_2)\Leftrightarrow w_2(e_1)>w_2(e_2)$ implies that $w_1(e_1)=w_1(e_2)\Leftrightarrow w_2(e_1)=w_2(e_2)$. In particular, if we order the edges in a non-decreasing order according to $w_1$, then we have also ordered them in non-increasing order according to $w_2$.

Now, recall that any minimal spanning tree (for $(G,w_1)$) can be found by Kruskal's algorithm (lemma -- https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95625/109876), so in particular there is an order on the edges which is non-decreasing for $w_1$ such that $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E}')$ is selected. This same order is non-increasing for $w_2$, and can therefore be used to find a maximum spanning tree (for $(G,w_2)$) using Kruskal's algorithm. But since Kruskal's selection process is independent of the actual weights (and depends only on the ordering and whether the current edge creates a cycle or not), the algorithm will output $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E}')$ again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but still I have a question maybe stupid question but when it says w1 and w2 for e1 does it mean an edge with two weight ? if yes so what about e2 ? e2 with w1 and w2 again and does it mean e2 has 2 different weight value ?

Comment: A weighted graph can be defined as a pair $(G,w)$ where $G=(V,E)$ is a graph and $w$ is a weight function where $w$'s support is included in $E$. In this problem, we consider the two following weighted graphs $(G,w_1)$ and $(G,w_2)$ (on the same underlying graph). But in each of the graphs each edge only has one weight.

Comment: @graphicart86 Yes, you are starting off with two different edge-weighted graphs. The two graphs have the same vertex and edge sets, but different weight functions. If you order the edges as $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_m$ and if this lists the edges of the first graph in increasing order of weights, then this also lists the edges of the second graph in decreasing order of weights.